# Database (Expo SQLite) cannot be created in the apk file

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development, eas, expo-sqlite

So I recently made an app which uses Expo SQLite package to store items. My goal was obviously to keep the data saved when a user closes the app and then opens it again. It works perfectly fine inside the Expo Go app, but when I ran `eas build -p android --profile preview` to build an apk file, the database could not be loaded because I made the app not to load until the database was initialized. Like this:

```
const [DBIsInitialized, setDBIsInitialized] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        await createDatabase();
        setDBIsInitialized(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error);
      }
    }
    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (DBIsInitialized) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [DBIsInitialized]);

  if (!DBIsInitialized) {
    return null;
  }
```

I've already asked a developer about this and he says that it's probably because the database needs to be stored inside the device storage. Is that right?

Expo SQLite version: ~11.1.1

Any solutions for this? Your help will be appreciated.